# Key error when using dictionary definitions

Tags: python

I am using the following code which is producing a key error (1, 2) and I'm not sure why:

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request
import json


myurls2 = {}
for x in range(1, 15):
    for y in range(1, 87):

        strvar1 = "%s" % (x)
        strvar2 = "%s" % (y)

        with open("C:\\Python33\\NASDAQ Stock Strings\\NASDAQ_Config_File_{}_{}.txt".format(x,y),"r") as f:
            myurls2[x,y] = f.read().replace('\n', '')            
            #print("myurls_" + str(strvar1) + "_" + str(strvar2) + "=", myurls2[x,y])
            #print(myurls2[x,y])

            URLS = [myurls2[1,1],myurls2[1,2],myurls2[1,3],myurls2[1,4],myurls2[1,5]]
```

When the line '#print(myurls2[x,y])' is uncommented you can see that the dictionary definition is correctly iterating through the text files that generate the dictionary values, but the dictionary keys cannot then be referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first pass through, where `x=1` and `y=1`, you have only defined `myurls[1,1]`. In other words, you have yet to define `myurls[1,2]` (or any of the other `myurls`).

Are you sure that `URLS` should not be defined after the `for x` and `for y` loops are complete?

As @inspectorG4dget notes, it might be that `URLS` needs de-denting out of scope of the for loops.

Comment: It might be helpful if you noted in your post, that the last line needs to be dedented out of the scope of both for-loops

Comment: Yes, you are correct, the URL statement needed moving out of scope of the dictionary declaration above. I'm new to Python, so I am still getting used to the functionality of indenting. Rather than list a series of myurls2 dictionary entries, i.e. [1,1],[1,2] etc can i not just say URLS = [myurls2[x,y]] to include all dictionary values?

Comment: @user3045351 For all dictionary values, use `URLS = myurls2.values()`